Azure OpenAI On Your Data API: How to pass Azure AI Search (the Index name) to the Chat completion
I've edited the question:
I want to migrate or pass my index_name from Azure OpenAI (with my data) in the bot in Python. I tried to adjust this code_1 as well as this code_2 but it did not work.
The single index consists in 4 consolidated files in .txt format into ONE single JSON array. The index is stored in Azure OpenAI service.
I tried to replicated this exercise Azure Cognitive Search client library for Python but it did not work.
The Chat in Playground Azure OpenAI with my data (uploaded into the Azure blob storage) recognized the information of my data (the majority), without mapping the fields (this done by Azure into content and title). But when I mapped the fields of the JSON array in parse mode, the Chat does not recognized my data. I followed this similar approach: Azure Open AI failing to read Search Index?.
The JSON array of the consolidated files (named as aqueduct with 200 Site ID, definitions, impact_mm and explanation) are parsed as follow (I created a "dummie" content of the data). Notice that some sub-fields are int64 such as the values of Site_ID and question. I tried to convert them into string and the bot did not recognized them.
[
    {
        "aqueduct": [
            {
                "Site_ID": 1,
                "Site_Name": "some name",
                "BU_RC_Name": "some BU name",
                "Country": "some country",
                "Street": "some street",
                "postal_code_City": "some postal",
                "Risk_indicators": {
                    "Total_Overall_water_risk": "some value",
                    "Physical_risk_quantity": "some value",
                    "Physical_Risk_Quantity": "some value",
                    "Regulatory_and_reputational_risk": "some value",
                    "Baseline_Water_Stress": "some value",
                    "Baseline_Water_Depletion": "some value",
                    "Interannual_variability": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability": "some value",
                    "Groundwater_table_decline": "some value",
                    "Riverine_flood_risk": "some value",
                    "Coastal_flood_risk": "some value",
                    "Drought_risk": "some value",
                    "Untreated_Connected_Wastewater": "some value",
                    "Coastal_eutrophication_potential": "some value",
                    "Unimproved_No_Drinking_Water": "some value",
                    "Unimproved_no_sanitation": "some value",
                    "Peak_RepRisk_country_ESG_risk_index": "some value"
                },
                "Year_and_type_of_model": {
                    "Water_Supply_Optimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Optimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Optimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Optimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Optimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Optimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Optimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Business_as_Usual_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Business_as_Usual_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Business_as_Usual_2030": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Business_as_Usual_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Business_as_Usual_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Business_as_Usual_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Business_as_Usual_2040": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Business_as_Usual_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Pessimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Pessimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Pessimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Pessimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Pessimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Pessimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Pessimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Pessimistic_2040": "some value"
                }
            },
            {
                "Site_ID": 2,
                "Site_Name": "some name",
                "BU_RC_Name": "some BU name",
                "Country": "some country",
                "Street": "some street",
                "postal_code_City": "some postal",
                "Risk_indicators": {
                    "Total_Overall_water_risk": "some value",
                    "Physical_risk_quantity": "some value",
                    "Physical_Risk_Quantity": "some value",
                    "Regulatory_and_reputational_risk": "some value",
                    "Baseline_Water_Stress": "some value",
                    "Baseline_Water_Depletion": "some value",
                    "Interannual_variability": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability": "some value",
                    "Groundwater_table_decline": "some value",
                    "Riverine_flood_risk": "some value",
                    "Coastal_flood_risk": "some value",
                    "Drought_risk": "some value",
                    "Untreated_Connected_Wastewater": "some value",
                    "Coastal_eutrophication_potential": "some value",
                    "Unimproved_No_Drinking_Water": "some value",
                    "Unimproved_no_sanitation": "some value",
                    "Peak_RepRisk_country_ESG_risk_index": "some value"
                },
                "Year_and_type_of_model": {
                    "Water_Supply_Optimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Optimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Optimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Optimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Optimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Optimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Optimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Business_as_Usual_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Business_as_Usual_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Business_as_Usual_2030": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Business_as_Usual_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Business_as_Usual_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Business_as_Usual_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Business_as_Usual_2040": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Business_as_Usual_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Pessimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Pessimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Pessimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Pessimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Pessimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Pessimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Pessimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Pessimistic_2040": "some value"
                }
            },
                .
                .
                .
            {
                "Site_ID": 201,
                "Site_Name": "some name",
                "BU_RC_Name": "some BU name",
                "Country": "some country",
                "Street": "some street",
                "postal_code_City": "some postal",
                "Risk_indicators": {
                    "Total_Overall_water_risk": "some value",
                    "Physical_risk_quantity": "some value",
                    "Physical_Risk_Quantity": "some value",
                    "Regulatory_and_reputational_risk": "some value",
                    "Baseline_Water_Stress": "some value",
                    "Baseline_Water_Depletion": "some value",
                    "Interannual_variability": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability": "some value",
                    "Groundwater_table_decline": "some value",
                    "Riverine_flood_risk": "some value",
                    "Coastal_flood_risk": "some value",
                    "Drought_risk": "some value",
                    "Untreated_Connected_Wastewater": "some value",
                    "Coastal_eutrophication_potential": "some value",
                    "Unimproved_No_Drinking_Water": "some value",
                    "Unimproved_no_sanitation": "some value",
                    "Peak_RepRisk_country_ESG_risk_index": "some value"
                },
                "Year_and_type_of_model": {
                    "Water_Supply_Optimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Optimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Optimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Optimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Optimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Optimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Optimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Business_as_Usual_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Business_as_Usual_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Business_as_Usual_2030": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Business_as_Usual_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Business_as_Usual_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Business_as_Usual_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Business_as_Usual_2040": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Business_as_Usual_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Pessimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Pessimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Pessimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Pessimistic_2030": "some value",
                    "Water_Stress_Pessimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Supply_Pessimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Water_Demand_Pessimistic_2040": "some value",
                    "Seasonal_Variability_Pessimistic_2040": "some value"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    [
        {
            "risk_indicator": "risk indicator name",
            "definition": "some text"
        },
        {
            "risk_indicator": "risk indicator name",
            "definition": "some text"
        },
        {
            "risk_indicator": "risk indicator name",
            "definition": "some text"
        },
        {
            "risk_indicator": "risk indicator name",
            "definition": "some text"
        },
        {
            "risk_indicator": "risk indicator name",
            "definition": "some text"
        },
        {
            "risk_indicator": "risk indicator name",
            "definition": "some text"
        },
        {
            "risk_indicator": "risk indicator name",
            "definition": "some text"
        },
        {
            "risk_indicator": "risk indicator name",
            "definition": "some text"
        },
        {
            "risk_indicator": "risk indicator name",
            "definition": "some text"
        },
        {
            "risk_indicator": "risk indicator name",
            "definition": "some text"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        },
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        },
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        },
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        },
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        },
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        },
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        },
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        },
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        },
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        },
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        },
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        },
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        },
        {
            "Category": "some category",
            "Mitigation_measure": "some text"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "question": 1,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 2,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 3,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 4,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 5,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 6,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 7,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 8,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 9,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 10,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 11,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 12,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 13,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 14,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        },
        {
            "question": 15,
            "explanation": "some explanation"
        }
    ]
]


what are you expecting? you want to merge all this .txt files into single index?

@JayashankarGS Thanks for the reply. I`ve edited the question for better clarification.

When you create an index, you will get the following options for parsing mode:

If you choose any of the options related to JSON, you will not get the correct results. This is because the format of the file is .txt, and none of your files have a standard JSON object. In the first file, there are two fields that are not present in the remaining files, and the same issue occurs with fields in the other files.
When parsing as a JSON array, the system reads the first file and creates an index with the parsed fields, but the remaining fields are not considered. In your case, it is only indicator and Definition.

As a result, when you use chat completion on this data, you won't get the proper results.
Even if you create a custom index with the required fields, it will still have the data from the three files but not in a single record. For example, the first record will only have indicator and Definition, with the remaining fields being empty or null; the second record will have question and explanation, with the rest being null.
For chat completions, all fields should be in a single JSON object with multiple records. Therefore, with the current file format and JSON lines, only text or default parsing mode will work.

Before your response, I had already implemented the approach you suggested, which yielded not satisfactory results since the subfields vary among the JSON arrays. But I achieved excellent outcomes by assigning titles to each JSON array file. The current index comprises the following subfields: content, filepath, title, url, id, chunk_id, and last_updated. However, the pending question pertains to passing this index to the Python bot.

yes, i guess assigning titles will get the index but it doesn't give proper results when you do chat completions because every file is of different json fields.

the standard  json fields in your case is which works perfectly with python bot is
 {
  "indicator":"xxxx",
  "Definition":"xxx",
  "question":1,
  "explanation":"xxx",
  "Category":"xxx",
  "Mitigation measure":"xxx",
   "Site_ID": 5,
   "Site_Name": "xxx",
   "BU_RC_Name": "xxx",
   "Country": "xxx",
    "Street": "xxx",
    "postal_code_City": "xxxx",
    "Risk_indicators": {...},
   "Year_and_type_of_model": {..}

 },
...
]```

Understood, thank you. Once the index is completed, this is stored in my Azure platform, but I still cannot manage to pass/migrate the index to my bot in python

yeah. so, go by text parsing mode then it will take whole content and gives output correctly in python bot.

@NaveenSharma I am still working on it. Once it is solved i will accept it

@JayashankarGS the bot is not able to recognize when creating an index for the parsing mode but when i upload my data through chat playground and the index is created with "title" and "content" subfields, the bot does the semantic work. And I still cannot manage to pass the index into Python using the code: Azure OpenAI On Your Data API Reference

Give default parsing mode or text and try.

@JayashankarGS I followed your approach: I created a combined list of records (from the 4 files) with missing fields set to "None". When importing the .txt file to index (using pasing mode as JSON array) only the objects from the first combined file with strings were identified, the rest of the objects were not detected in the `Field name

Yeah. i have already mentioned about that in solution. Also you json should be in a format that all fields should be there in every file or define the index with the fields you required.

I`ve tried many attempts. Maybe I am missing something, for instance, what do you mean by "For chat completions, all fields should be in a single JSON object with multiple records. Therefore, with the current file format and JSON lines, only text or default parsing mode will work"...I followed this approach and manually configurated semantic in Azure Platform but the Playground did not recognized the data. Also, I am not able to retrieve my data form Azure Ai Search in the bot (in Python).

the standard json fields in your case is which works perfectly with python bot is [  {   "indicator":"xxxx",   "Definition":"xxx",   "question":1,   "explanation":"xxx",   "Category":"xxx",   "Mitigation measure":"xxx",    "Site_ID": 5,    "Site_Name": "xxx",    "BU_RC_Name": "xxx",    "Country": "xxx",     "Street": "xxx",     "postal_code_City": "xxxx",     "Risk_indicators": {...},    "Year_and_type_of_model": {..}   }, ... ] like this your files should contain fields. All files should contain this fields

Not all fields have the same number of categories. For instance, there are 20 indicators and its 20 definitions, 40 questions with its 40 explanations, and 201 site_IDs with 200 corresponding objects. This leads to many empty fields, for example, there will be 161 empty fields for {definition: []}..., which causes issues with the chat functionality.

yeah. that is why i asked you to use default mode parsing or text mode parsing. if you still want read parse json you need to have correct json files.
